# how Import Root CA into the login Keychain to get support for selfsigned SSL certificates via the command line

Tags: macos, keychain, self-signed-certificate

I'm trying to add a CA to the login keychain for getting SSL support for safari\Google chrome browser.I use the below security command

`sudo security add-trusted-cert -r trustRoot -k "/Users/maya/Library/Keychains/login.keychain" "/tmp/certs/test.cer`"

The cert got added to login keychain successfully, but the the browser is not able to recognize certificate authority, getting the error 'ERR_cert_authority_invalid'.

Thanks,

Comment: When you go into the Keychain Access, what does it show as the trust settings for the added certificate?  Also: do you need a self-signed cert or are you just trying to end-run the Certificate Industrial Complex? There are valid reasons for a self-signed or internal cert, but if you just want certs for free, Let's Encrypt is a great option.

Comment: Thanks @gaige. I have an application called Download Manger which run on users machine(like how bittorrent works ). Basically its run on http://localhost:xxxx/. i want to make this to SSL secure to resolve some security issue.  However i found a solution and now its working fine!!!!!